# How see number of comments on joomla

Tags: joomla, comments

helo all!

i want to see the numbers of comments of any article on frontpage in joomla.

how can I add this plugin or module for the readers know the numbers of commments per article...

sorry for my english :D

Answer (score 1):

Which component are you using for commenting?  There are a bunch out there - in terms of displaying comments on the front page, I think you would probably have to contact that developer to see if they have a plugin to help with that, or write some code of your own to assist with that (it shouldn't be too hard - some templates have that functionality out of the box even).

Ultimately it will depend on which component and if the developer has already created something to go along with that plugin.